# use custom attribute in js for an element

Tags: javascript, element

For Example:

like I can use `this.href` for an anchor element and I have created a custom attribute dialog. I am unable to use that custom attribute dialog for anchor tag
`this.dialog` isn't working.

working:

```
<a onclick="this.href='anything'">anything</a>
```

not working:

```
<a onclick="this.dialog='anything'">anything</a>
```

Note:
dialog work same for me as href but it open in a dialog box.

Comment: You are setting the _property_ `dialog`, not the attribute. And the `<a>` tag does not have a property `dialog`. (Note that `dialog` is technically not valid as attribute either).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the element's `href` works because the default behavior (following the link) is still followed.

The attribute you've introduced, `dialog`, has no affect on the default behavior. Clicking the link will still cause the browser to follow it's `href`.

If you want to change the behavior of a link and have the click open some kind of dialog, you need to do a lot more than just assign a value to a random property on the element. You need to suppress the default and define your own inside the event handler.

Comment: "The attribute…" should be "The property…". ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Use DOM to access HTML attributes

```
element.hasAttribute('foo'); element.getAttribute('foo'); element.setAttribute('foo', value); element.removeAttribute('foo');
```